# Creating new processes

Tags: c, process, fork

I am creating new processes by forking:

```
printf("original process = %d\n", getpid());
fork();
printf("parent = %d; child = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
fork();
printf("parent = %d; child = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
if(fork() == 0){
        printf("parent = %d; child = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        if(fork() == 0){
                    printf("parent = %d; child = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        }    
}
fork();
printf("parent = %d; child = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
```

and I want to print out how many processes I have created. My approach as seen above is not the best way of printing how many processes have been created. So my question is: how can we print how many new processes have been created each time we fork without having some kind of loop?

Comment: I count 18, but I probably missed something. And `getppid()` doesn't return a child process id. It returns the active *parent* process id.

Comment: I bid 2*2*2*2 + 2*2 - 1 = 19.

Answer (score 1):

Each successful call to fork creates a new process, and both the parent and the child return from `fork()`. The child will get 0 as return, the parent the PID of the child.

```
printf("I am the root %d\n", getpid());
if (fork() == 0)
    printf("I am %d, child of %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
if (fork() == 0)
{
    printf("I am %d, child of %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    if (fork() == 0)
        printf("I am %d, child of %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}
if (fork() == 0)
    printf("I am %d, child of %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
```

And so on...

The problem in your code is that you are printing the text in some cases without checking the return value of `fork()`, so these lines will be printed both by the parent and the child. With my code, each process prints just one line, on creation.

Answer (score 0):

As each creates/spawns a child process, 
Based on the order in which the fork() is called 
Totally 24 child process are created, this is how its done

> **1st fork()**; (has **4** more fork() calls) 
>   **2st fork()**; (has **3** more fork() calls) 
>   **3st fork()**; (has **2** more fork() calls) 
>   **4st fork()**; (has **1** more fork() calls)

So the totall number of child process would be **4! - 1**, that is **4x3x2x1 = 24 - 1**
**23 child process are created**